# How do I apply multiple transform-origin on Javascript/HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I apply 2 different CSS transforms to a single HTML element  with different transform-origin for each?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to work out the `matrix` value for each and then add them together using matrix mathematics. Their are some online calculators that can help with this

http://angrytools.com/css-generator/transform/

Answer (score 0):

Set two DOM's of the same size, Set transform-origin for each individually

```css
div{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
.origin1 {
  background-color: orange; /*Set to transparent*/
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
}
.origin2 {
  background-color: blue;
  transform-origin: 300px 300px;
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="origin1">
  <div class="origin2"></div>
</div>
```